# iptables routing input and forward paths

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing

I would like to know the flow of a packet given the configuration below.

Suppose that I setup an adhoc network between my android phone and a NIC on my linux box. I then setup the android phone to use the NIC, wlan1, as its default gateway.

I have a proxy listening on port 8080. I want to redirect packets to that proxy.

I then want to forward those packets to the internet. So I forward them to wlan0 which is connected to my router.

According to the diagram here:
http://www.iptables.info/en/structure-of-iptables.html

A packet either goes through the input stream (i.e. to my proxy) or the forward stream (i.e. to wlan0) . Is there no way to redirect and forward?

Additionally, the diagram lists "routing decisions" -- for instance in the input stream -- with only one arrow leaving the routing decision box. What kind of decision is one where there is only one outcome?

Comment: Consider drawing a diagram that shows your setup.